# How to add attributes to aspect/compiler-generated property?

Tags: postsharp

I'm adding a property to a class and have my Aspect set up like this:

```
[PSerializable]
public class MyAspect : InstanceLevelAspect
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [IntroduceMember]
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

My target class is then decorated with the `[MyAspect]` attribute.

When Postsharp adds the `MyProp` property to the target class, it does not include the `MaxLength` attribute on the generated property.  The property in the Aspect class includes it, but the property added to my target class does not.

I need the attributes specified for the property in the aspect definition to be added to the property added to my target class.  How can I add the attributes to the generated property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To intruct PostSharp to copy the attribute, you need to use `[CopyCustomAttributes]` ([doc](https://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_copycustomattributesattribute)), so your aspect would look like this:

```
[PSerializable]
public class MyAspect : InstanceLevelAspect
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [IntroduceMember]
    [CopyCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute))]
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```